# Why is the result of content().bytes() ignored when deal with Resource in Spring MVC tests?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying to write a unit test checking that user can download a PDF file from a syte. I use spring-boot-starter-parent of version 2.1.2.RELEASE.

Method in controller:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/download", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile() {
        Resource resource = ...;
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
            "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + '"').body(resource);
    }
```

Test method:

```
    @Test
    public void shouldFail() throws Exception {
        byte[] anyBytes = new byte[]{};
        mockMvc.perform(get("/download"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE))
            .andExpect(content().bytes(anyBytes));
    }
```

In controller method I provide existing PDF-file as a Resource.
Next in test I compare response body with a byte array that is certain not equal to my PDF resource. So test is expected to fail. But it passes.

After some research i found that It is no matter what byte array is provided to content().bytes() - test passes anyway. What is interesting, bytes() method throws AssertionError inside, but it is swallowed somehow.

Is it a bug or I make something wrong?

Comment: try to add `.andReturn()` to complete the chain

Comment: @AlexSalauyou - thanks for reply. I've tried this - it didn't help